# WPF TreeView throws 'System.StackOverflowException' when tree depth is too deep

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, .net-4.5, .net-4.5.2

I found that the application will exit due to a stackoverflowexception.
My application creates a TreeView, with a lot of items, nested up to 6 depth or so. It encounters stackoverflowexception and exits. The application is fine using .Net 4.5.1 but however, when it uses .Net 4.5.2 it threw the Exception.

I can not provide the original code but I was able to reproduce it through a sample WPF project.

The code logic

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MenuItem root = new MenuItem() { Title = "Menu" };
            root.IsExpanded = true;
            MenuItem parent = new MenuItem() { Title = string.Format("lv {0}", 0, 0) };
            parent.IsExpanded = true;
            root.Items.Add(parent);
            trvMenu.Items.Add(root);
            for(int i = 1; i < 200; i++)
            {
                MenuItem childItem = new MenuItem() { Title = string.Format("lv {0}", i) };
                childItem.IsExpanded = true;
                parent.Items.Add(childItem);
                parent = childItem;
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++ )
                trvMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Title = string.Format("item {0}", i) });
        }
    }

    public class MenuItem
    {
        public MenuItem()
        {
                this.Items = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
        }

        public string Title { get; set; }
        bool _isExpanded;
        public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> Items { get; set; }
        public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get { return _isExpanded; }
            set
            {
                _isExpanded = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:self="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="154">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" Name="TextRow"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Row="2" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="LightGray">
            <TreeView Name="trvMenu"
                      VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                      VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
                      >
                <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}"/>
                    </Style>
                </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:MenuItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded}" Value="true">
                            </DataTrigger>

                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The exception only occurs when I let the TreeView to be expanded as default and when the depth is around 200+ (I tried 150 which was fine).

Anyone knows how to fix it or have a workaround or any suggestions?

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1137159/wpf-treeview-throws-system-stackoverflowexception-when-tree-depth-is-too-deep